# VB.NET "System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'Xyz' context has changed since the database was created." after adding a property

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been given a VB.NET project, using EF 6 code first. I've created a migration and successfully updated the database, and the app compiles and run fine.

But when I add a property to my DbContext class, I get the following error message on runtime:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'MyDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Here is an extract of the MyDbContext.vb file:

```
Public Class MyDbContext
    Inherits DbContext

    [Multiple properties]

    ' I add this line
    Public Property DbEnvironments As DbSet(Of DbEnvironment)
End Class
```

If I remove the line above and recompile it, the program runs without an error message.

This is the DbEnvironment.bn file:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Public Class DbEnvironment

    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property CurrentEnv As Integer

End Class
```

Comment: Are you saying that following the steps in the article linked to in the error message does not work?

Comment: Have you already tried the solution provided in the link?